# Can disk be damaged during cloning?

Tags: disk, cloning

Let's say I am using GParted iso for cloning an X disk to Y disk. Can X disk be damaged e.g if power would go off during cloning?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is always a chance of damage to a disk if the power abruptly goes off. Make sure to keep power to the machine while copying/moving!